# Azure Point to site Port can't connect to Azure VM or Port

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have created a azure vm on ubuntu tls ubuntu 16.04 and i have created a azure vpn gateway as mentioned in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal
the problem is i have successfully connected to the vpn but when i try to access any port that is allowed for my virtual network only. I get an error of 10060. Which means that timed out. I am behind a D-Link router. Do i need to connect my router to the vpn or my pc is enough to get connected to the vpn to access the vm azure.
[image: i want to access ssh through my Vnet only]
As seen in the picture i want my vpn gateway or vnet to access the ssh port only and restricted to others. But it gives 10060 error

[image: VPN Connection Successful]
VPN connection is successful. What can be the problem. If i change the source to any it will connect perfectly
There's no IP overlapping.

Comment: No source is Virtual Network and destination is any see SSH on port 22

Comment: yes but i also mentioned that any port can be accessed only through the vnet

Comment: well, try allowing your vpn ip address range, as you are technically accessing ssh not from within vnet

Comment: i have tried that also. Both the address range and subnet range and also the public ip but nothing.

Comment: i tried all the ranges. but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overengineering it.

If all you want is to lock down your SSH endpoint yet still be able to come in from a dynamic IP, in your NSG allow SSH from `Any` and install `knockd`
(Port Knock daemon) on the VM —

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortKnocking#Server_Setup

> #### What is Port Knocking ?
>
> Port knocking is a simple method to grant remote access without leaving a port constantly open. This preserves your server from port scanning and script kiddie attacks.
>
> To utilize port knocking, the server must have a firewall and run the knock-daemon. As the name conveys, the daemon is listening for a specific sequence of TCP or UDP "knocks". If the sequence is given correctly, then a command is executed; typically the source IP address is given access through the firewall to the port of an application (such as SSH).

Should be available in most distros via *apt/yum/whateverSuSEusesNowadays*. [Tarball here](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock) if you really must compile from source.

Comment: well i is not a bad idea but still for the future i wanna know as to why is it not working?

Comment: If you permit any->any in the NSG, can you SSH into that VM over its public IP address?

Comment: Add 2 NSG rules, `Virtual Network -> any, port 22/TCP` and `IP.SPACE.OF.YOUR.P2S.VPN -> any, port 22/TCP`. That should do it. If still no go, `tcpdump` from the VM see if you get traffic from the Point-to-site, the return path may be broken, in which case check effective routes on the VNET.

Comment: One more thing make sure your source IP address is the Point-to-site one when you invoke the SSH client on your local machine.